# where to save 100 NSStrings + other type

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I need to save somewhere 100 strings (quiz questions iphone app). Also, some datatype which will store the the information if the right button was pressed. What is the best way to store these values, in NSArray, NSMutableArray or in .plist?

Thank you in advance

Comment: is your data static (doesn't it change while using the app)?

Comment: NSMutableArray would be best. You could do plist file, but 100 strings wont take much memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a PList to add the data to you project and then load them into you NSDictionary, you can read in a PList into a NSDictionary with -[NSDictionary initWithContentsOfFile:]

Comment: Thank you. I'll implement it this way.

Answer (score 0):

For each separate question create an **NSMutableDictionary** and store it into **NSMutableArray** is the best way to work with such process.

**Code for reference:**

```
    NSMutableArray *arTemp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i =0; i < 10; i++)
    {
            NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [tempDict setObject:@"object1" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"value%i", i]];
            [tempDict setObject:@"object1" forKey:@"type"];
            [arTemp addObject:tempDict];
            [tempDict release]; 
    }
```

Is that clear to you?

Comment: Well, sounds good can you point me to some example? I mean how to store it into NSMutableArray.